# Can Demons "eat" ghosts?

Tags: dungeon-lords

I'm reasonably sure the answer is no, but at Monster Payday I (or when hiring) can you sacrifice a ghost to the demon? Or not, since it's not a monster, and the icon is a monster icon and ghosts aren't monsters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can't sacrifice a ghost to a demon. From the final page (24) of [the rules](http://czechgames.com/files/DL_rulebook_EN.pdf), under the description of ghosts:

> Ghosts can not be used to pay the cost
>   for a demon.

And then later, under the description of demons:

> Heh, heh. That's me. I'm always happy
>   to help you reduce your overhead. But
>   don't think you can get away with
>   feeding me ghosts. They just go right
>   through me.